# Why doesn't the TF MNIST example work with original data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I've adjusted the data loading of the [TensorFlow MNIST example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html) to use the [original MNIST data](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). The original example gets > 0.80 accuracy after 100 epochs. My adjusted example (set `use_original = False` to use it) gets only about 0.09 - 0.10 accuracy (which is just random). Could you please explain why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""MNIST with Tensorflow."""

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

from struct import unpack
import gzip
from numpy import zeros, uint8

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

use_original = True


def get_labeled_data(imagefile, labelfile):
    """
    Read input-vector (image) and target class (label, 0-9).

    Return
    ------
    tuple of lists
    """
    # Open the images with gzip in read binary mode
    images = gzip.open(imagefile, 'rb')
    labels = gzip.open(labelfile, 'rb')

    # Read the binary data

    # We have to get big endian unsigned int. So we need '>I'

    # Get metadata for images
    images.read(4)  # skip the magic_number
    number_of_images = images.read(4)
    number_of_images = unpack('>I', number_of_images)[0]
    rows = images.read(4)
    rows = unpack('>I', rows)[0]
    cols = images.read(4)
    cols = unpack('>I', cols)[0]

    # Get metadata for labels
    labels.read(4)  # skip the magic_number
    N = labels.read(4)
    N = unpack('>I', N)[0]

    if number_of_images != N:
        raise Exception('number of labels did not match the number of images')

    # Get the data
    x = zeros((N, rows * cols), dtype=uint8)  # Initialize numpy array
    y = zeros((N, 1), dtype=uint8)  # Initialize numpy array
    for i in range(N):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print("%s: %i" % (imagefile, i))
        j = 0
        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                tmp_pixel = images.read(1)  # Just a single byte
                tmp_pixel = unpack('>B', tmp_pixel)[0]
                x[i][j] = tmp_pixel
                j += 1
        tmp_label = labels.read(1)
        y[i] = unpack('>B', tmp_label)[0]
    enc = OneHotEncoder()
    enc.fit(y)
    y = enc.transform(y).toarray()
    return (x, y)


epochs = 20000


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                          strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def eval_network(dataset, correct_prediction):
    correct_sum = 0
    total_test = 0
    for i in range(dataset.labels.shape[0] / 1000):
        feed_dict = {x: dataset.images[i * 1000:(i + 1) * 1000],
                     y_: dataset.labels[i * 1000:(i + 1) * 1000],
                     keep_prob: 1.0}
        test_correct = correct_prediction.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
        correct_sum += sum(test_correct)
        total_test += len(test_correct)
    return float(correct_sum) / total_test


def add_score(filename, mnist, scoring, epoch, other=''):
    with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
        train = eval_network(mnist.train, scoring)
        test = eval_network(mnist.test, scoring)
        myfile.write("%i;%0.6f;%0.6f;%s\n" % (epoch, train, test, other))


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv),
                                              reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# Data loading

if use_original:
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
else:
    mnist = lambda: None
    setattr(mnist, 'train', lambda: None)
    setattr(mnist, 'test', lambda: None)
    setattr(mnist.train, 'images', lambda: None)
    setattr(mnist.train, 'labels', lambda: None)
    setattr(mnist.test, 'images', lambda: None)
    setattr(mnist.test, 'labels', lambda: None)
    xs, ys = get_labeled_data('mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz',
                              'mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
    mnist.train.images = xs
    mnist.train.labels = ys
    xst, yst = get_labeled_data('mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz',
                                'mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
    mnist.test.images = xst
    mnist.test.labels = yst
for i in range(epochs):
    if use_original:
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)  # This works
    else:
        # This doesnt work
        batch = (xs[i * 50:(i + 1) * 50], ys[i * 50:(i + 1) * 50])
    if i % 100 == 0:
        add_score('accuracy.csv',
                  mnist,
                  correct_prediction,
                  i)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0],
                              y_: batch[1],
                              keep_prob: 0.5})
add_score('accuracy.csv', mnist, correct_prediction, epochs)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read, and yet more context to read off-site. Would it be possible to break out and annotate your changes? Most likely is you have a re-shape missing or gone wrong so the images are being presented to the network effectively with the pixels shuffled. As you are using CNN, it won't be able to learn from arbitrary re-ordering, there needs to be an image with short-distance correlation.

Comment: @NeilSlater The changes are everything which gets active when you use `use_original = False`. So the mistake is most likely in `get_labeled_data`. I will test in a minute if shuffling is the reason.

Comment: I don't think shuffling is the reason. The labels are not ordered and as only 100 epochs (5000 seen examples of 60,000 available ones) are necessary to get an accuracy over 0.8, I doubt this is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The data needs to be loaded as `numpy.float32` (and normalized by dividing it through `255`).